# wicked_pdf and Rails won't load css with @import

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, pdf, wicked-pdf

So I'm using Wicked_pdf and I tried pdfkit as well.

Having the same issue with both. Which is, the pdf conversion fails when I try and reference a stylesheet that imports parts of bootstrap.

This is what I'm doing in my controller

```
html = render_to_string(partial: "users/direct_deposit_info.html", layout: "layouts/pdf")
UserMailer.send_email(current_user.email,'Direct Deposit Information',content, html)
```

And this is what's in the stylesheet that keeps breaking things and causing it to fail:
This is my print.css.scss:

```
@import 'bootstrap/variables';
@import 'bootstrap/print';
@import 'general';
```

This is what I'm doing in my layouts/pdf. If I remove the reference to the 'print' stylesheet, it will convert to pdf successfully and everything works fine except my pdf is not completely styled. If I keep the 'print' reference in, then it breaks

```
<%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag "fonts" %>
<%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag "print" %>
<%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag "application/direct_deposit_check" %>
```

And this is the error I get:

```
Failed to execute:
"/Users/bdog/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/wkhtmltopdf" -q                  
"file:////var/folders/cn/9n6mzxt52d1c5j2lt3868rkr0000gn/T/wicked_pdf20140524-51775-1bjnzku.html"     
"/var/folders/cn/9n6mzxt52d1c5j2lt3868rkr0000gn/T/wicked_pdf_generated_file20140524-51775-  1ysvtz9.pdf" 
Error: PDF could not be generated!
 Command Error:
```

So my question is, in Rails, is there a way to get the css from these imports into my html without it freaking out?

I need the bootstrap print and variables css so that way my general.css file has access to the variables that the bootstrap files contain.

*EDIT*
If I add a normal rails stylesheet link tag to 'print.css.scss' this is what I get in my rendered html file:

```
<link href="//localhost:3000/assets/print.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

If I use the wicked_pdf_stylsheet_link_tag "print", then I get the same error and in my rendered html file there is no link reference or anything.

Comment: Like is there a way to render out my 'print.css.scss' so that way I get all the css that the imports would render into a string or file that I could then just plug into my html? I know the whole purpose of import is to do just that put it's clearly not working

Comment: Works for me with sass-rails gem and `@import 'bootstrap/print';` Is there anything custom in your print css?

Comment: Hmmm mine still isn't working. And nope, nothing custom. it literally is those 3 lines that begin with the imports. I always get this in my log and then it just stops.
    `Completed 200 OK in 2194.6ms (Views: 0.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.9ms)
"***************\"/Users/bdog/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/wkhtmltopdf\" -q         \"file:////var/folders/cn/9n6mzxt52d1c5j2lt3868rkr0000gn/T/wicked_pdf20140527-54509-vq5gz.html\" \"/var/folders/cn/9n6mzxt52d1c5j2lt3868rkr0000gn/T/wicked_pdf_generated_file20140527-54509-1jmlyev.pdf\" ***************"`

Comment: That tells me it is working, on OSX there's an issue where you have to click the wkhtmltopdf icon in the dock before it finishes the request. Could that be your issue?

Comment: I tried, all i get is an exec icon that says "wkhtmltopdf_darwin_386" and clicking it doesn't change anything. I save my pdf to a file after it is rendered and the line referencing my 'print.css.scss' stylesheet never shows up in my saved file

Answer (score 0):

Ok good news but still don't understand what's happening. It turns out that the links are rendering properly.
In my _pdf.html.erb layout file I link the stylsheets like so:

```
<style type='text/css'>
<%= raw Consumer::Application.assets.find_asset('fonts.css.scss').body %>
<%= raw Consumer::Application.assets.find_asset('print.css.scss').body %>
<%= raw Consumer::Application.assets.find_asset('application/direct_deposit_check.css.scss').body %>
```

And when I save my rendered html to a file and open it in a browser, I do indeed get the properly styled page I am looking for. However, since I need the page is meant to be in an email, it doesn't actually get sent because my server is still stopping like I explained earlier.

Upon further investigation, since I am saving my rendered html email to a file and then converting that file to a pdf and also saving that pdf to a file, I found that the raw html gets rendered and saved but the pdf doesn't and so I'm assuming that the line that is having issues is the line that creates my pdf in my controller:(the attach variable is the raw html file that I rendered in my first post `render_to_string(partial: "users/direct_deposit_info.html", layout: "layouts/pdf")`)

```
File.delete("#{Rails.root.to_s}/tmp/dd_raw.html") if File.exist?("#{Rails.root.to_s}/tmp/dd_raw.html")     
File.write("#{Rails.root.to_s}/tmp/dd_raw.html", attach)

# Create new pdf from string
kit = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(attach)

# save to file
file_path = "#{Rails.root.to_s}/tmp/direct_deposit_info.pdf"
File.delete(file_path) if File.exist?(file_path)

File.open(file_path, 'wb') do |file|
  file << kit
end
```

EDIT

I also tried running the wkhtmltopdf command from the command line and used --ignore-load-errors to no avail. It rendered a blank pdf. 
I did get the following: `Warning: Failed loading page http: (ignored)`
I imagine it has something to do with me referencing urls in my font css.
like so: `src: url(http://localhost:3000/assets/metric-thin.eot);`

Comment: Referencing urls to the same application in development can cause an infinite hang, since most dev servers can only serve a single request at a time. While it is performing the first request, it stops and waits to gather what's needed to fulfill the request, but fullfilling the request requires making another request, which is blocked.

Comment: Ah ok got it, so is there a solution to get around this?
Currently I am doing this: `@font-face {
  font-family: 'Metric';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 100;
  src: url(http://localhost:3000/assets/metric-thin.eot);
  src: url(http://localhost:3000/assets/metric-thin.eot) format("embedded-opentype"), url(http://localhost:3000/assets/metric-thin.woff) format("woff"), url(http://localhost:3000/assets/metric-thin.ttf) format("truetype"), url(http://localhost:3000/assets/metric-thin.svg#Metric) format("svg");
}`

Comment: Does a full system path like: `url('/Users/Ldrbrandon/code/my_app/app/assets/metric-thin.woff')` work?

Comment: No that wasn't working. What I ended up doing was base64 encoding my font files in my css. That worked like a charm, it just makes my rendered html file kinda big. I used the `asset-data-url('custom-font.woff')` method which base encodes it at runtime i believe. Thanks again for the help narrowing down my problem @Unixmonkey